# Does Xcode have an internal configuration for its .ssh keys and its Github account?

Tags: xcode, github, ssh

Yesterday I changed my .ssh keys, on two Macs and on my github account.

On the first machine, on the command line, git pull and push performed as expected. 
On the same machine, Xcode source control performed push and pull as expected.

One the second machine, git on command line still worked fine, but authentication failed every time I attempted a pull or push using XCode source control, from any repo.

I checked the .git/config file, and the URLs looked fine. I tried cloning a new repo from origin and that worked fine. But even then, a push pull from the newly cloned repo failed.

Finally, I used XCode itself to create a new .ssh key and then everything worked again, but I don't understand why. As far as I can tell, all it did was:

1 add another keypair to .ssh

2 add the public key to github

...in other words, exactly as it was before.

Does anyone know what was different in Xcode, that made this work?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode use unencrypted RSA private key, so you can run ssh-keygen with `-m PEM` argument

eg.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "your_email@example.com" -m PEM
```

---

btw.
IntelliJ platform IDE such as Android Studio, IDEA, if use Settings Repository feature with ssh git repo. also require unencrypted RSA private key.